# Trying to remove an object on-screen when clicked in Java doesn't work

Tags: java, vector, mouseevent

The purpose of the Java applet is as such: A ball is bouncing around the screen. The size and speed of this ball can be changed via scrollbars. The user can press and drag the mouse on the screen to draw rectangles. The ball will bounce off of these rectangles as well. The bounds of these rectangles are stored in a vector. When a rectangle is clicked, it (and all other rectangles at that point) are removed from the vector (and the screen).

The problem I'm currently having is that clicking to remove an object doesn't work.  What I'm doing is getting the point of where I clicked, and stepping through each element of the vector and seeing if it contains the point, and if it does, remove it from the vector.  Here's the method.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m)
{
    if (!ball.flag)
    {
      Vector<Rectangle> v;
      v = (Vector<Rectangle>)ball.r;
      Point p;
      p = new Point(m.getPoint());

      boolean done = false;
      int i = 0;

      for (Rectangle rect : v)
      {
        if(rect.contains(p))
        {
          v.removeElement(i);
          System.err.print("Element removed");
          continue;
        }
        i++;
        if(i>=v.size())
          done=true;
      } 
      ball.r = v;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would use a for loop, not a while loop, since you know how many times you need to loop, and since this will prevent you from skipping the last item in the loop. Also, for something like this, I usually loop backwards, starting at `i = v.size() - 1` and going until `i == 0` since this usually selects the top-most visualized object before objects further down the z-order.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestions, first of all.  I changed it to a For Each loop, as you'll see above.  Should I just use a good ol' fashioned for loop?  Also, I quite like your idea with looping backwards.  I implemented that as well, and now I'll edit the OP to reflect that.  The problem I'm getting now is that I get a Java.util.ConcurrentModificationException at the line that has the for each loop.

Comment: If you're going to remove an element, then you'll want to use a ListIterator and remove the item with the iterator.

Comment: Why would I need to do that?  Can't I just use the built-in removeElementAt() method of the Vector object?  If I'm counting down from the size of the array, can't I just remove element (i-1)?

Comment: I'd, personally, use `v.remove(rect)` instead, removing the need to track the index at all.

Comment: That will cause problems if you do it while you're looping through it, especially with a for-each loop. Removing an item changes the size of the Vector, and the size is used to end the loop, hence your error message.

Comment: Okay! Progress! Like MadProgrammer suggested, I'm now using v.remove(rect), and it does remove the element, but I'm still getting a ConcurrentModificationException, and now I can't see the rectangles as I draw them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to use an Iterator. Like so:

```
ListIterator<Rectangle> i = v.listIterator();

while(i.hasNext())
{
    Rectangle r = i.next();

    if(r.contains(p))
        i.remove();
}
```

This will remove elements from the list in a safe way.

Comment: This makes sense, and would be very efficient, but where do I put 'rect'? Is it in its own for loop?  Because otherwise rect will always be pointing at one rectangle.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Didn't take that into consideration.

Comment: Alright, so, thanks for the help thus far, but I'm getting an error that says "cannot find symbol method contains(java.awt.Point)".  I believe it's saying that i doesn't have a method contains for points.

Comment: Disregard the above comment.  It was typed before you posted the edit.  Modifying code and testing now.

Comment: That definitely fixed it.  The issue we have now is that when the vector is empty, we can't see the "shadow" of the rectangle.  By shadow, I mean the rectangle that is constantly drawing until mouseReleased is triggered.

Comment: Disregard that one also.  It was just that we weren't drawing the "shadow" if the vector was empty.  Not sure what I was thinking when I wrote that.  Thanks again for all of your help!